# Angular Material - disable descending sort

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have REST API that only supports ascending sort, is it possible to disable descending sort direction in MatTable but keep ascending direction and no sort option?

Comment: share screenshot of code and elaborate your problem statement clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only override the function sort of the MatSort

```
  @ViewChild(MatSort,{static:true}) sort: MatSort;

  ngOnInit()
  {
    this.sort.sort=(sortable: MatSortable)=>{
      if (this.sort.active != sortable.id) {
        this.sort.active = sortable.id;
        this.sort.direction = sortable.start ? sortable.start : this.sort.start;
      } else {
        this.sort.active=''
      }
      
      this.sort.sortChange.emit({active: this.sort.active, direction: this.sort.direction});
    }
    this.dataSource.sort=this.sort
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer your question?

> If you want to prevent the user from changing the sorting order of any
> column, you can use the `matSortDisabled` binding on the `mat-sort`, or
> the `disabled` on a single `mat-sort-header`.

[From the docs](https://material.angular.io/components/sort/overview#disabling-sorting).

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just override `getNextSortDirection` and hardcode it to return always your desired value.

Look at source code: https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/material/sort/sort.ts#L181C3-L181C46

```
this.sort.getNextSortDirection = () => '';
```

Thanks to @eliseo

Comment: Or another way - `<th *matHeaderCellDef mat-header-cell mat-sort-header="name" [disabled]="tableSort.active === 'name'">Name</th>` where `#tableSort="matSort"`. This is helpful to prevent `matSortChange` event every time.